# Cordova Admob plugin error in Android App with conflicts

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I have a project with Cordova on Android Studio and all was working fine. I have added the Cordova Plugin Admob (pro), from [Github office site](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro). When I add the plugin and try to debug on my device, I have an error (build project works fine). If I remove the plugin and create again the project with the command "*cordova create platform android*" all work fine.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

In the console, I can see that:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;","sources":[{}]}

My project "android" has these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+"
// SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
```

}

I have added the Google Play Services in the SDK Manager, but I think that I have a conflict with the Google Play Services library or something...

Can someone tell me how can I fix it? I have read some similar questions, but I have no idea where to start...

**EDIT:** Information from the official plugin:

3. Build error with message "Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/..."

Caused by duplicated google-play-services.jar.

This plugin properly referenced to the google-play-services.jar in your android sdk with tag framework , which is recommended by Google team.

While some other plugins contains the jar, or depends on a plugin named com.google.playservices which is already deprecated.

Please list all plugins and check which plugin use it improperly, then report a bug to that plugin.

Comment: Have you already tried with https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution was remove push plugin and remove admob pro. After, I added FIRST admob pro plugin and after push plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The AdmobPlugin Pro does this when used in conjunction with anything else that uses the play libraries, such as analytics, etc.

Try a different admob plugin such as https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-plugin-admob-simple

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-simple
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is worked for me: 
First remove the admob and phonegap-push plugins:
Then add again admob with version 5.4.2 and phonegap-plugin-push version 1.2.3

Commands:

cordova plugin add admob@5.4.2

cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push@1.2.3